# gwt multi-module vs single-module project

Tags: maven, gwt, multi-module

I've seen the GWT Expenses app from GWT SDK is using single module structure.

Is this a best practice? Are there any cons in having the project split into multiple maven modules, i.e:

- client
- shared
- server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GWT compiler and DevMode don't really care about how you structure your build system as long as all of the client and shared resources are available on the GWT classpath and the server components have been compiled into the webapp's WEB-INF/classes directory (or lib/foo.jar) if you're using DevMode's built-in Jetty server.

Comment: Yes, but having the server code in the same project(like GWT Expenses), makes the build slower if you only changed some server-side logic. In this case you'd only want to build and deploy the "server" module.

Comment: I should have written: Configure your build environment in the way that makes sense for your project.

Comment: Thanks! I take it there are no cons in splitting the project like above.